# Magento zoom image with new theme in product detail page

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento. I create new theme and want to create with new look and feel. I want product view detail page use zoom image feature as the same it's default but it not work. I know it's cause from javascript file and it's css not imported.

- How can i use this feature and what css or javascript should i import?

Answer (score 0):

Hello add skin/frontend/default/default/css/styles.css from line no 990 to 1013 ( product images) into your theme css

add javascript code into product details page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
    });
//]]>
</script>
```